# UITableViewCell backgroundColor behind accessoryType + section indexes

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hopefully it's visible in this image:

[image]

I am trying to make the background draw behind the section index, but unfortunately the background is white behind the section index and it's also white where the UIAccessoryType is being drawn (not pictured).

I am using a UITableViewCell subclass and setting the background with:

```
[self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackgroundPattern"]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `self.contentView` is, as its name suggests, only the content view. Try just do `self.backgroundColor` (a property of `UIView`) or `self.backgroundView`.

Comment: Adding a subview to the `backgroundView` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`self.contentView` never draw image over `accessory view` and `thumbnail image`.

To use background color of cell, draw image as `backgroundColor` or make an instance of `UIImageView` and set it as `backgroundView` of cell